# HTML 5 canvas game objects getting stuck after collision

Tags: javascript, graphics, html5-canvas, collision-detection

Please help i tried a couple of things but whenever i move the small object to the larger one it gets stuck after collision detection. Here is my code its easy enough to understand.
i have also tried to detect collision detection on individual sides of the other object.

```
// Setup requestAnimationFrame
requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame  ||  
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||  window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


// Game objects
var player = {
width:50,
height:50,
x:50,
y:50,
speed:100,
color:'#3C1BE0'
       };

var wall={
width:50,
height:150,
x:300,
y:100,
color:'#E01B5D'
        };


// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
},false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
},false);

//check collisions
var collisions=function(){


}

// Update game objects
var update = function (modifier) { 

//test for collisions 

//player collision with wall(red cube)

if(player.x+player.width>wall.x && 
   player.x<wall.x+wall.width   &&
   player.y<wall.y+wall.height  && 
   player.y+player.height>wall.y 
  )
   {
     player.speed=0;
   } 

//player collission with canvas
if(player.x < 0 )
{
    player.x=0;
}
else if(player.x+player.width> canvas.width)
{
    player.x=canvas.width-player.width;
}
else if(player.y <0 )
{
    player.y=0;
}
else if(player.y+player.width>=canvas.height)
{
    player.y=canvas.height-player.height;
}


if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
player.y -= player.speed*modifier;
}
if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
player.y += player.speed*modifier;
}
if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
player.x -= player.speed*modifier;
}
if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
player.x += player.speed*modifier;
}

};

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,400);

ctx.fillStyle=wall.color;
ctx.fillRect(wall.x,wall.y,wall.width,wall.height);

ctx.fillStyle=player.color;
ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height);
};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
var now = Date.now();
var delta = now - then;

update(delta / 1000);
render();

then = now;
requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Let's play this game!
var then = Date.now();
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you are never setting the speed to something above 0 after you have set it to zero on the collision.

```
if(player.x+player.width>wall.x && 
   player.x<wall.x+wall.width   &&
   player.y<wall.y+wall.height  && 
   player.y+player.height>wall.y) {
     player.speed=0; // this never gets unset
}
```

You would need to probably figure out where the player wants to go based on the keystroke and calculate a delta.  If the delta is allowable (not colliding), then you update the player's position, otherwise you don't apply the delta.

Comment: Thanks for your response SB. Can you suggest how would i go about doing that or should i use a completely different collision detection system

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem.I have added the direction of the keyboard to the arguments and created a stand alone collision detection function.if you think i make any improvements to my collision code i would appreciate any useful input.

```
var collisions=function(sprite1,sprite2){
return sprite1.x < sprite2.x + sprite2.width &&
sprite1.x + sprite1.width > sprite2.x &&
sprite1.y < sprite2.y + sprite2.height &&
sprite1.y + sprite1.height > sprite2.y;

}

if(collisions(player,wall)){
if(player.y+player.height>wall.y &&
    40 in keysDown
  )
{
  player.y=wall.y-player.height;
}

if(player.y<wall.y+wall.height  &&
  38 in keysDown
  )
{
  player.y=wall.y+wall.height;
}
if(player.x+player.width>wall.x && 
    39 in keysDown
   )
{
  player.x=wall.x-player.width;
}
if(player.x<wall.x+wall.width   && 
 37 in keysDown
   )
{
  player.x=wall.x+wall.width;
}

}
```